# JSON string to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Im working on consuming REST response from web service that returns JSON string. The result response from AJAX is that i get alot of info and I use JQuery.parseJSON(result) to get the value from each JSON Tag.

From this result response I need to format it so it can fit to Highchart. 
Highchart need it to be formatted to:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2],
    name: 'LA',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2]
}]
```

What is the best way for me to loop through the result data and create JSON string like Highchart wants to have? Here below is a start of solving this but I cant finish.

```
success: function (result) {
    var resultobj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    for (i = 0; i < resultobj.length; i++) {
        var objt = resultobj[i];
        // what TODO?????
        highchartresultarray.push(objt.name);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What to do in the loop depends on what the data you receive from this web service looks like. Can you post an example of that too?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your resultdata?

Comment: [{"Time":"23.11.2012","name":"Jp","data":"15,1919360247338"},
{"Time":"23.11.2012" ,"name":"Gu","data":"4"},
{"Time":"19.11.2012" ,"name":"Se 3","data":"10"}]

Comment: Are you sure Highcharts expects this format ?

Comment: Your expected HighCharts series format does not look right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Highcharts but based on the series array in the question (which I think has a small mistake because you have shown an object with has multiple properties with the same name - each name and data property should be encapsulated within their own respective objects from the looks of it)  and the sample data you have provided, I have made a simple function which should give you the expected result - the premise of the function is to create an empty array for holding your objects, then iterate over the raw data putting the bits you need from the raw data into an empty object and pushing the populated object into the container array on each iteration - i don't explain things very well! so here's the code -

```
function highchartdata(data) {

highchartarray = [];

$.each(data,function(i,v){

    var highchartobj = {};

    highchartobj.data = v.data.split(',');

    highchartobj.name = v.name;

    highchartarray.push(highchartobj);

});

return highchartarray;
```

};

and heres a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nuqJD/10/